# Problems with latitude/longitude grid in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, labeling, latitude-longitude, esri-grid-format, composer-manager

I try to produce a thematic map in QGIS, like this one done in MapInfo:

[image]

I want to do this in QGIS. I work in projection "Albers-Siberia" projection ( `PROJ.4: +proj=aea +lat_1=52 +lat_2=64 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=105 +x_0=18500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +towgs84=28,-130,-95,0,0,0,0 +no_defs`). The latitude/longitide grid I made with help of this [article](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html). I have got the following result:
[image]

I have a problem:

As you can see grid lines don't intersect in the North Pole. How
    can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. In the future it would be better to separate your questions, in order to make answering and finding the right answer easier, thank you.

Comment: how did you draw the grid?

Comment: With the help og this article. 
   https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html. new print composer > add map >in item project made a new grid > CRS>WGS84 > interval 10/10